# Undergrad CV – listing posters you presented but did not author

Tags: conference, cv, poster

There seems to be a bias, particularly among more established researchers, to only include posters that they presented. There seems to be a trend towards not including (or including as *abstract accepted*) posters where they **are** listed as an author, but someone else presented.

My question is the reverse of that: If you were not involved in the project (thus no authorship), but presented the poster at a conference, would you include that on your CV?

Example: I attended a conference this year; my PI was supposed to present two of their posters, but couldn’t make it at the last minute. We’re currently working on extensions of that research, so I was familiar with the topic, but I wasn’t involved in those particular projects. I was also presenting at that conference, and so I presented my PI’s posters as well.

Is it acceptable to include those on my CV, with a note about “presented by [self] at [event]”?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is acceptable. However, I would not list it in my "publication section", rather in a separate section called "Paper/Poster Presentations".

If you received any certificate (or letter) after the presentation, then that is a plus.

Comment: What kinds of certificates/letters might be offered?

Comment: @Nat Something like this: "This is to certify that Mr. James Bond presented a paper/poster entitled 'How to have a license to kill' in the International Workshop on Terror Avoidance 2017, held at University of Suspense during November 31 - 35, 2017".

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can list whatever you want on your CV as long as it is accurate and not presented in a misleading manner. The main question is whether this is really an important asset and does not leave the reader asking “so what?”.

The only thing that you presenting that poster testifies is that you were once challenged and trusted with presenting somebody else’s work (and hopefully gained some experience). Whether you did a good job with this is impossible to tell for the reader. Presenting your own work at the conference is arguably a dozen times more valuable than this.

As you probably get a recommendation letter from PI as well, it may be more wise to have them mention this event in a positive manner, e.g., if they got feedback on your performance or can state why they trusted you with this task.

Finally, be sure that you do not list this event in a manner that may make somebody who just skims your CV think that you managed to present more posters about your own work than you actually did. Even if your CV is technically accurate, they may feel deceived.

Answer (score 1):

I say No.  You take credit for your own research product, and don't take credit for other people's research.  Giving a poster presentation on somebody else's research is a favor, not a CV element.